# Observation number by group

Tags: r, sas

In R I have a data frame with observations described by several values one of which is a factor. I have sorted the dataset by this factor and would like to add a column in which I would get a number of observation on each level of the factor e.g.

```
factor   obsnum
a        1
a        2
a        3
b        1
b        2
b        3
b        4
c        1
c        2
...
```

In SAS I do it with something like:

```
data logs.full;
    set logs.full;
    count + 1;
    by cookie;
    if first.cookie then count = 1;
run;
```

How can I achieve that in R?

Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `rle` (run length encoding) and `sequence`:

```
x <- c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c")

data.frame(
    x=x,
    obsnum = sequence(rle(x)$lengths) 
)

  x obsnum
1 a      1
2 a      2
3 a      3
4 b      1
5 b      2
6 b      3
7 b      4
8 c      1
9 c      2
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the ddply() solution

```
dataset <- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c"))
library(plyr)
ddply(dataset, .(x), function(z){
  data.frame(obsnum = seq_along(z$x))
})
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution using base R, assuming your data is in a `data.frame` named `dfr`:

```
dfr$cnt<-do.call(c, lapply(unique(dfr$factor), function(curf){
  seq(sum(dfr$factor==curf))
}))
```

There are likely better solutions (e.g. employing package `plyr` and its `ddply`), but it should work.